# MySQL - how to lock a single row?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, create-table

My aim is to create a system to book trips. My system is built in *MySQL + PHP*. I'm using InnoDB as engine in MySQL.

When an user choose which trip he wants to book, I want the ipothetic page "*.php" to lock one of those trip for some times (ex. 10 minutes) and after this time release it.

Which is the best way to lock the trip in the DB?

Notice that I didn't talk about rows or table because I'm asking for the **easiest** way to implement this kind of feature and I'm not sure if mines is that one. So I've tried to design a table to contain the trips, and look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Trip (
  id INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  descr VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB
```

Comment: I'd set a flag in that table, let's call it `locked (timestamp)`, set it `now` in the "ipothetic page .php". Next time you want to access that row, check if `now` minus the saved timestamp is greater than 10mins, ... got my idea?

Comment: ...to not use a **transaction** *nor* **LOCK** of MySQL's framework and implement it "natively" in the table, updating that column in that row if the difference between the timestamp and "now" is greater than 10mins!
Got your idea? :)

Comment: But that doesn't fit my aim. Imagine this scenario: I have 10 users that are looking for the same trip, so they are locking them. The 11th user will see that there are no trips available. Instead in your scenario all the users except one could book the trip.

Comment: I'm more than happy to learn it would be done with _transaction_ or _LOCK_! I just posted how I'd do it, not saying it's the best way..

Comment: i was trying to use the SQL script on my database , but it shows error ... would please give the correct SQL code ?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty done, so sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Worked .. let me try to give you an answer .. wait 5 minutes please

Comment: and +1 from me for this kind effective question , this kind of question would be really helpful for new programmers

Comment: Thank you :)
In fact I'm a Junior programmer that wants to be Senior ASAP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is your Ticket table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Trip (
  id INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  descr VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB
```

**Let me visualize your user table as this ( just for testing )**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Now You need add an extra table where you can track your users booking order ( Example like this )**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trip_track` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trip_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now Every time you insert a booking query you need to insert user_id,ticket_id and timestamp ( You can use date or Mysql's default time stamp )

Then whenever user tries to book any ticket use a Query to check the time difference between current time and the timestamp from the database

That's it! .. see? that's simple :)

Comment: Nice answer. *"Now Every time you insert a booking query you need to insert user_id,ticket_id and timestamp"*. They could use a trigger (to automate things) if they want as an added option.

Comment: yeah , trigger is nice option too .